# MultiWAN has slow failover

Tags: networking, router, tomato, failover

I have the latest Tomato Firmware using the MAX option.

I have the device configured for failover to the 2nd WAN if the main internet connection for WAN 1 goes down.

The issue I have is that WAN 1 seems to hold a DHCP lease from the network and it takes about 3 minutes to fully failover despite having a 1 minute option checked. If I manually release the DHCP IP Address the failover is instant. Is this a bug or is there a way to make failover most instantaneous?

Thanks.

Comment: You created an ambiguous tag that I suspect will not be helpful in attracting answerers.  Does [multiwan] refer to the old OpenWrt script or generic multi-WAN?

Answer (score 0):

Change the "checking"-mechanism from `traceroute` to `ping`, works better in some scenarios, and is much faster.

Just remember that a trace over 20 hops with a timeout of 3 seconds is roughly 3 minutes (3 sec * 3 times * 20 hops = 180 sec)...